# Don't read specific token at a given point

Tags: antlr, antlr4

At some point in my grammar file, I want ANTLR to read my input as 2 tokens instead of one.
In my source file I have the value

```
12345.name
```

and the lexer consumes

```
12345.
```

as a FLOAT-Token. At this specific point in the source file I want ANTLR to read this as

- 12345 (INT)
- . (DOT)
- name (NAME)

Is there a way to tell ANTLR that it should ignore FLOAT-Types at some given point?

This is my current .g4 file:

```
grammar Quest;
import Lua;

@header {
package dev.codeflush.m2qc.antlr;
}

/*
prefixed everything with "m2" to avoid nameclashes
*/

m2QuestFile
    : m2Define* m2Quest* EOF
    ;

m2Define
    : 'define' NAME m2DefineValue
    ;

m2DefineValue
    : ~('\r\n' | '\r' | '\n')
    ;

m2Quest
    : 'quest' NAME 'begin' m2State* 'end'
    ;

m2State
    : 'state' NAME 'begin' (m2TriggerBlock | m2Function)* 'end'
    ;

m2TriggerBlock
    : 'when' m2Trigger ('or' m2Trigger)* ('with' exp)? 'begin' block 'end'
    ;

m2Function
    : 'function' NAME funcbody
    ;

m2Trigger
    : m2TriggerTarget DOT m2TriggerEvent DOT m2TriggerSubEvent DOT m2TriggerArgument
    | m2TriggerTarget DOT m2TriggerEvent DOT m2TriggerArgument
    | m2TriggerTarget DOT m2TriggerEvent
    | m2TriggerEvent
    ;

m2TriggerTarget
    : NAME
    | INT
    | NORMALSTRING
    ;

/*
not complete
*/
m2TriggerEvent
    : 'button'
    | 'enter'
    | 'info'
    | 'item_informer'
    | 'kill'
    | 'leave'
    | 'letter'
    | 'levelup'
    | 'login'
    | 'logout'
    | 'unmount'
    | 'target'
    | 'chat'
    | 'timer'
    | 'server_timer'
    ;

m2TriggerSubEvent
    : 'click'
    | 'chat'
    | 'arrive'
    ;

m2TriggerArgument
    : exp
    ;

DOT
    : '.'
    ;
```

I'm using the Lua grammar from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/lua/Lua.g4

My current sample input file looks like this:

```
quest test begin
    state start begin
        when kill begin
        end

        when "12345".kill begin
        end

        when 12345.kill begin
        end
    end
end
```

Where the first two work as intended but the third one doesn't (because the lexer reads '12345.' as one FLOAT-Token)

Comment: Would disallowing requiring at least one digit after the dot for float literals globally be an option?

Comment: @sepp2k Yes that works for me, too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar need in my grammar [where I wanted to issue multiple tokens (2 actually) for a single match](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLLexer.g4#L198) under a specific condition (here: when a dot is directly followed by an identifier, including a keyword).

```
// Special rule that should also match all keywords if they are directly preceded by a dot.
// Hence it's defined before all keywords.
// Here we make use of the ability in our base lexer to emit multiple tokens with a single rule.
DOT_IDENTIFIER:
    DOT_SYMBOL LETTER_WHEN_UNQUOTED_NO_DIGIT LETTER_WHEN_UNQUOTED* { emitDot(); } -> type(IDENTIFIER)
;
```

A [helper function](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/mysql/MySQLBaseLexer.cpp#L1193) is needed to emit the extra token(s):

```
/**
 * Puts a DOT token onto the pending token list.
 */
void MySQLBaseLexer::emitDot() {
  _pendingTokens.emplace_back(_factory->create({this, _input}, MySQLLexer::DOT_SYMBOL, _text, channel,
                                               tokenStartCharIndex, tokenStartCharIndex, tokenStartLine,
                                               tokenStartCharPositionInLine));
  ++tokenStartCharIndex;
}
```

which in turn requires custom handling of the token production. You have to [override](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/mysql/MySQLBaseLexer.cpp#L1047) the `nextToken` method in your token stream, to consider the pending token list before returning the next real token.

```
/**
 * Allow a grammar rule to emit as many tokens as it needs.
 */
std::unique_ptr<antlr4::Token> MySQLBaseLexer::nextToken() {
  // First respond with pending tokens to the next token request, if there are any.
  if (!_pendingTokens.empty()) {
    auto pending = std::move(_pendingTokens.front());
    _pendingTokens.pop_front();
    return pending;
  }

  // Let the main lexer class run the next token recognition.
  // This might create additional tokens again.
  auto next = Lexer::nextToken();
  if (!_pendingTokens.empty()) {
    auto pending = std::move(_pendingTokens.front());
    _pendingTokens.pop_front();
    _pendingTokens.push_back(std::move(next));
    return pending;
  }
  return next;
}
```

Keep in mind: the lexer rule still issues its own token (which I set to be an `IDENTIFIER` here), which means you only have to issue the additional tokens.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it as soon as I can and accept your answer if it works for my case.
Because this is a private project, it may take me a few days until I finally get my hands on it again.

Comment: I could successfully implement your example for my project and accepted your answer accordingly. However, I managed to work around my problem by simply removing the FLOAT Token from the Lua grammar and replaced it with a parser rule since I don't really need that specific token for my purposes.